# How to detect previous bar

Tags: pine-script

I'm wondering how to detect the previous bar inside the code, not 'visual' solution via plot and offset parameter

```
indicator('test', overlay=true)

up = (high[1] + low[1]) / 2 <= low //I want to mark one bar before
down = (high[1] + low[1]) / 2 >= high //I want to mark one bar before

barcolor(color = up ? color.new(color.lime, 0) : na, offset = -1) //this work like I need
barcolor(color = down ? color.new(color.red, 0) : na, offset = -1) //this work like I need
```

but how I can do it not in plot with 'offset = -1' parameter?

Comment: I also am looking for the solution ...